# Does Windows 8.1 Secure Boot need a TPM chip?

Tags: windows-8.1, secure-boot, tpm

I've seen conflicting information about the need for a TPM chip when enabling Secure Boot in the UEFI BIOS.

Is a TPM (Trusted Platform Module) chip needed for Secure Boot?

Thanks

Edit:
Thanks Ramhound for your comment:

> Please post the conflicting information. Either the firmware supports
>   it or it doesn't. Which means it either can be enable or it cannot be
>   enabled. So just enable it?

Example of conflicting information:

> Secure Boot does not require a Trusted Platform Module (TPM).

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824987.aspx

> Secure Boot. PCs with UEFI firmware and a Trusted Platform Module
>   (TPM) can be configured to load only trusted operating system
>   bootloaders. ... Secure Boot and Measured Boot are only possible on
>   PCs with UEFI 2.3.1 and a TPM chip.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/dn168167.aspx

I'd rather know if a TPM is needed before I enable Secure Boot. The HDD is in MBR format at the moment, with Legacy BIOS, I believe that for Secure Boot the disc needs to be in GPT format with UEFI only. If that is so, the hard drive would need to be formatted to enable Secure Boot. There is a TPM header on the board, so I presume there is no built-in TPM chip.

Comment: Please post the conflicting information.  Either the firmware supports it or it doesn't.  Which means it either can be enable or it cannot be enabled.  So just enable it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no conflict.

> Secure Boot and **Measured Boot** are only possible on PCs with UEFI
>   2.3.1 and a TPM chip.

Secure Boot can use but does not require TPM. Measured Boot requires TPM.

And you certainly don't need to wipe the drive to convert to GPT. Check method 2 & 3 in http://www.thewindowsclub.com/convert-mbr-to-gpt-disk